# Rails RSpec unit test fails on user attribute, image file type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, carrierwave

I've tried this a few different ways and am unclear on why the various permutations of the user unit tests I've written keep failing for testing the file type of the image attribute of the user object.

Here's what I currently have...

## models/user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  validate :image_size_validation
  validates_format_of :image, with: %r{\.(png|jpg|jpeg)\Z/}i, message: "image must be png, jpg, or jpeg", allow_nil: true

  def image_size_validation
    errors[:image] << "should be less than 5MB" if image.size > 5.megabytes
  end
end
```

## uploaders/image_uploader.rb

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
end
```

## spec/models/user_spec.rb

```
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, username: "zoidberg", image: "image.png") }

  it "has a valid image file" do
    expect(user).to be_valid
    expect(user.image).to be_valid
    expect(FactoryGirl.build(:user, username: "Farnsworth", image: "image.jpg")).to be_valid
  end
```

Puzzlingly, if I don't specify `username: <something>`, the test will fail with `Username is invalid`, despite it working in every other test and being built into the factory.

## spec/factories/user.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    first_name  Faker::Name.first_name
    last_name  Faker::Name.last_name
    sequence(:username) { |n| "#{n}#{Faker::Internet.user_name}#{Faker::Number.number(5)}#{Faker::Hipster.word}" }
    sequence(:email) { |n| "#{n}#{Faker::Hipster.word}#{Faker::Number.number(5)}#{Faker::Internet.email}" }
    phone  Faker::Base.numerify('##########')
    password  Faker::Internet.password(6, 20)
    state  Faker::Address.state_abbr
    city  Faker::Address.city
    image Faker::Avatar.image
    sequence(:zip) { |n| "#{n}#{n}#{n}#{n}#{n}" }
    seeking_coach true
    accept_email true
    accept_phone true
  end
end
```

I also tried this `it { should have_valid(:image).when('image.jpg', 'image.png', 'image.jpeg')}`, which I thought would work but clearly does not.

Comment: `be_valid` is meant to be used on objects, not attributes of objects.  I would imagine your formatting validation is because calling image on the object will return an uploader, not the string

Comment: So what is the appropriate syntax for an object attribute?

Comment: Rails returns `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Image image must be png, jpg, or jpeg`

Answer (score 0):

You can't test carrierwave by simply using a string to represent the file - "image.png". You actually need to open the file and upload it.

```
File.open(path_to_file) { |f| user.image.store!(f) }
```

where path_to_file represents the full path including filename for the file you are testing.

This is why the shoulda matcher doesn't work either:

```
it { should have_valid(:image).when('image.jpg', 'image.png', 'image.jpeg')} # won't work
```

You will need to write separate tests to check for each file type.

Also you should be building the user object - not creating it as it won't have a valid image at this stage:

```
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.build(:user, username: "zoidberg") }

it 'with png file it should be valid' do
  path_to_png_file = Rails.root + "spec/files/image.png"
  File.open(path_to_png_file) { |f| user.image.store!(f) }
  expect(user).to be_valid
end

it 'with txt file it should be invalid' do
  path_to_txt_file = Rails.root + "spec/files/text.txt"
  File.open(path_to_txt_file) { |f| user.image.store!(f) }
  expect(user).to_not be_valid
end
```

Naturally, you need to setup the paths in accordance with your test environment.

You don't need to test the actual image itself - it's effectively just an attribute for the user which you have validations for. If the image is invalid then user is invalid, but you could test for the validation errors to ensure they are related to image if you wish.

Comment: I hate to be so daft but I'm having a hard time implementing this. When I query `self.image.path` in rails c I'll get something like `"uploads/Dr_John_Zoidberg.png"`. So I tried `File.open("uploads/#{user.image}")` and `File.open("#{user.image.path}")` among other permutations but those will return either `NameError: undefined local variable or method uploads'` or `Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - uploads/`.

Comment: you need use File.open with the full path to an actual file on your system - as I have demonstrated in my example. Do NOT use user.image ... its that that you are trying to set.